# Android compare Button with Textview value

Tags: android, button, textview

Hell i am trying to compare textview value with button how  can i do it?

i tried this way but not working.

```
button xml - android:tag = "1"
```

Java

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id); 
string valu = btn.getTag();
string txt = textView.getText();

if(txt.equals(valu))
{
// do what you want
}
```

Comment: what is the issue you getting

Comment: Just print **valu** in your log and see if is it getting value of 1 or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
textView.getText().toString();
```

`getText()` returns a `CharSequence` not a `String`.
Because of that your `equals` must be false.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this.

```
if (b.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(tv.getText().toString())) {

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", 9000).show();
}
```